# Why am I getting connection issues when posting to a webserver, but only for a certain user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis

I am using the (standard) code below to post, then process a file on an IIS 7.5 web server.  This works fine for most users, however for one user we are having issues.

After a few about 10 seconds (whilst the original request is still running on the web server), the client machine shows an "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error.  It appears that it is trying to access the page: `http://servername/application/controller/UploadFile` url as a get request?

If we reduce the time it takes to process the file (on the server) then this issue does not happen.

It is user and not machine specific as the same error occurs when the user is logged on to a previous working machine.

What could cause just this user to have issues and nobody else?

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UploadFile", "DirectReport")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

    <div id="UploadedFilePlaceholder">
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UploadedFile)
    </div>    
</form>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var model = new DirectReportingIndexViewModel() { UploadedFile = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName) };

    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var path = SaveFile(file);
        var result = _directReportRunner.Run(path, file.FileName);
        model.DirectReportRunnerResult = result;
    }

    model.HasRun = true;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be caused by a setting within the registry:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050